# How pass the same props to every child in Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which is rendering conditional different components. I can't pass the same props in every place, because this destroy pretty code. How can I optimize this?

```
render(){
  const {what, y} = this.props.ddd

  return(){
    {what === "XXX" && <> <SmthComp1 x=y /> <SmthComp2 x=y /> }
    {what === "ZZZ" && <> <SmthComp3 x=y /> <SmthComp34 x=y /> }
    {what === "YYY" && <> <SmthComp5 x=y /> <SmthComp12 x=y /> }
    {what === "BBB" && <> <SmthComp6 x=y /> <SmthComp23 x=y /> }
    {what === "GGG" && <> <SmthComp7 x=y /> <SmthComp21 x=y /> }

  }
}
```

In fact, there are more props (not only x), that breaks the code. But they are always the same.

Every component has prop x with value y. I don't want pass this to every component.

Comment: this seems like a contrived example. do you have a real use case?

Comment: This is real example. I only used simpler names and variables to focus on the problem.

Comment: why are there all these components with the same name and the only difference is the number after them?

Comment: Because I wanted to show that these are different components. Yes this is an example but not contrived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a component map and store the props in a variable, like this:

```
render() {
    const {what, y} = this.props.ddd

    const componentsMap = {
        "XXX" : [SmthComp1, SmthComp2],
        "ZZZ" : [SmthComp3, SmthComp34],
        "YYY" : [SmthComp5, SmthComp12],
        "BBB" : [SmthComp6, SmthComp23],
        "GGG" : [SmthComp7, SmthComp21],
    };

    const componentProps = { x: y };

    return() {
        <>
        {componentsMap[what].map(Component => <Component {...componentProps} />)}
        </>
    }
}
```

You can put `componentsMap` outside the render method because it will not change.

Comment: thanks, but I'll just notice that `(componentsMap[what] || []).map( ` is more careful :)

Answer (score 2):

You can save props to a var and then spread them onto the component:

```
render(){
  const {what, y} = this.props.ddd
  const props = {x: y}

  return(){
    {what === "XXX" && <> <SmthComp1 {...props} /> <SmthComp2 {...props} /> }
    //...
  }
}
```